# Cannot find name in Typescript with MobX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I created simple MobX store:

```
import { observable, action, computed } from "mobx"

interface UserInterface {
  login: string
  email: string
  password: string
}

class User {

  @observable users: UserInterface[] = []

  @action addUser = (newUser: any) => {
    this.users.push(newUser)
  }

  @action logMe = () => {
    console.log("MobX works!");
  }

  @computed get userCount() {
    return this.users.length
  }
}

export const UserStore = new User()
```

And this is the beginning of the component that uses data from this store:

```
import withStyles, { WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles"
import { inject, observer } from "mobx-react"
import { UserStore } from "../../../stores/user-store"

interface RegisterFormProps extends WithStyles<typeof RegisterFormStyles> {
  userStore?: UserStore
}
@inject("userStore")
@observer
class LoginForm extends React.Component<RegisterFormProps> {
```

I have a tslint error in  `userStore?: UserStore` part. It's throwing the error: `Type error: Cannot find name 'UserStore'.  TS2304`. The path to this class is correct. If I change the type from UserStore to `any` it works but i want to avoid using the `any` type.

@Edit. The solution is to include this lines at the end of MobX store file:

```
const UserStore = new User();
export { UserStore }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
const UserStore = new User();
export { UserStore }
```

Answer (score 0):

`export const UserStore = new User()` means you are exporting variable `UserStore` and variable can not be use as type (but classes can). You have to export class `UserStore` use it in interface `userStore?: User`

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm getting error ```this.props.userStore.addUser is not a function``` How to export it correctly ?

Comment: Ok, but did error `Type error: Cannot find name 'UserStore'.  TS2304` disappear? And can you show also part of code where you define and call `addUser` method?

Comment: ```addUser()``` method is declared in store, look at first paragraph.

Comment: Yes, you right. But are you sure that you also have something like this in `Provider` component: `<Provider userStore = {userStore}>` where `userStore = new User();`

Comment: Yes, I put this reference to ```userStore``` in `Provider``` . What helped me: I added ```export default class User ...``` in the store file. But I think that's not much clean solution.

Comment: i suggest `export class User ...` and `import { Class } from ...` instead of export default.